# Writing connections in Graphql shorthand language?

Tags: graphql, relayjs, relay, graphql-js

how would you write a connection in graphql 0.7 shorthand ?

I see a list can be written like thus

```
var schema = buildSchema(`
  type Query {
    list: [Int]
  }
`);
```

But i can't see any documentation on how to write connections using short hand ? is the short hand syntax currently ready for usage with relay ?

expansion on question - how would you write this using shorthand syntax ? / root query.

```
var userType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'User',
  description: 'A person who uses our app',
  fields: () => ({
    widgets: {
      type: widgetConnection,
      description: 'A person\'s collection of widgets',
      args: connectionArgs,
      resolve: (_, args) => connectionFromArray(getWidgets(), args),
    },
  }),
  interfaces: [nodeInterface],
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by connections? It it object references / edge in the graph or?